# Does dividing the code into many file affect the performance

Tags: php, performance, frameworks

I have created a simple web application with own framework, and have a confusion that when I am dividing the php code into many files for reusability purpose, how much it will affect on performance. I have used CodeIgniter, but if I compare my framework, it has more files to process than the CodeIgniter.

Comment: It does have *some* impact; how much, depends on your system. The idea  is usually that not every file is needed during every request, though - how many files are you including per request on average?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it until it becomes a bottleneck, which is probably never (in all reasonable cases).

Comment: The performance without OPCode caching is very bad anyway, and if you do have OPCode caching then it couldn't possibly matter because the files are not read in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly answer this question you have to know various things about your hard drive in terms of it's IOPs, cluster size, seek time, sata connection, and/or RAID configuration.

Once you know this stuff and can calculate the time it takes to read a specfic file size from your disk then you can begin calculating how many requests per second would bog down your system.

Once you know this then you need to anticipate how many users are going to hit the system at once.

Another factor is CPU power and RAM speed because if your script is complex or uses a lot of memory then your CPU will be doing a lot of work and hopefully the RAM can keep up.

If you don't want to follow all these steps then run a `while()` loop that creates, reads, and deletes 5000 dynamic files between 4-50 KB each and use `microtime(true)` to bench it.

If you are on a shared hosting plan then your only option might be to implement the benchmarking idea at various peak and down times. I will bet that a 2am benchmark will fare much better than a 2pm one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, Number of files matters, but practically, it has a little affect. For example, if one file is divided into 2 files, but if you divide a file into 100 files then it might matter

Comment: This is as hazy an answer as the question is.